# Query to check for same cell value access table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a database with entries corresponding to different participants in a tasting experiment. All the entries are stored in a single table. The participants are each members of a family, with participants of a family given a family number (increments with family) (see image below).

[image]

I want to be able to check that for either 'Mother' or 'Father' of 'Child1','Child2', etc. within the same family, the location within the sweet, sour, bitter column is the same.

(I'm asssuming five queries will have to be run, one for each of the flavours).

To reiterate, I want to check for example if 'Mother' and 'Child1' within 'Family Number' 3 taste 'Bitter' in the same place (Which they do - 'Middle').

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this query

```
SELECT tr1.family_number, tr1.relationship, tr2.relationship
FROM taste records tr1
INNER JOIN taste records tr2 on tr1.family_number = tr2.family_number
WHERE (tr1.relationship = 'Father' or tr1.relationship = 'Mother') and
(tr2.relationship = 'Child1' or tr2.relationship = 'Child2' or tr2.relationship = 'Child3')
and tr1.sweet = tr2.sweet and tr1.bitter = tr2.bitter;
```